# inittab equivalent in fedora 15?

Tags: fedora, init, systemd

I have just installed Fedora 15 on my laptop. I want to study `/etc/inittab` as I studied it in RedHat 9.

I don't see any script in `/etc/inittab`. Also , the way the default runlevel can be changed in `inittab` has changed in Fedora 15.

If there is a good tutorial to study the changes in Fedora 15? I found https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Systemd, but was not much useful.

Comment: The Fedora Wiki article you linked to is probably the most comprehensive article you'll find. Is there something missing with it, or was it just too much information to wade through?

Comment: Yeah,it is too much information. I want is the only inittab substitution in fedora 16.

Answer (score 5):

From the systemd page you posted:

> **How do I change the default runlevel?**
>
> systemd uses symlinks to point to the default runlevel. You have to
>   delete the existing symlink first before creating a new one
>
> `rm /etc/systemd/system/default.target`
>
> Switch to runlevel 3 by default
>
> `ln -sf /lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target /etc/systemd/system/default.target`
>
> Switch to runlevel 5 by default
>
> `ln -sf /lib/systemd/system/graphical.target /etc/systemd/system/default.target`
>
> systemd does not use /etc/inittab file.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you want something like this...

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Disable_Clearing_of_Boot_Messages

```
sed /TTYVTDisallocate=/s/yes/no/ < /usr/lib/systemd/system/getty@.service > /etc/systemd/system/getty.target.wants/getty@tty1.service
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all.